# What is $A^2$ when $A$ is $m \times n$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

- How can one raise a matrix by the power on $n$? i.e. $A^n$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times q}$ and $n \in \mathbb{R}$

Is it defined as $A^n = AA^TAA^T...$ $n$ times? Holds for non-square matrices but I cannot find any source for it.

Is it defined as $A^n = AAAA...$ $n$ times? As showed [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixPower.html)? But this only holds if $A$ is a square matrix.

Comment: You are right that $A^n=AA\cdots A$ $n$ times only makes sense for square $A$.

Comment: These are questions of definition, not belief.

Comment: $AA^{\top}AA^{\top}\ldots$ looks more like $(AA^{\top})^n$ to me than $A^n$...

Comment: Another option is the Hadamard product.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

Comment: @jibounet If $n = 3$ it looks like $AA^TA$ if $n = 4$ looks like $AA^TAA^T$. So it's not like $(AA^T)^n$

Comment: @Mohammad : Ok. So I probably misunderstood your "... $n$ times".

Comment: @G.Sassatelli resolved. They are not the same

Comment: I will point out that your two definitions yield different results when $m=n$.  For example with $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ in calculating $A^4$, we have $AAAA=\begin{bmatrix}11&10\\5&6\end{bmatrix}$ but $AA^TAA^T=\begin{bmatrix}26&6\\6&2\end{bmatrix}$.  If we were to want to extend the definition of matrix power to nonsquare matrices, we would want the extended definition to have the same result as the usual definition for square matrices.

Answer (score 1):

An $a\times b$ matrix can be multiplied by a $c\times d$ matrix if and only if $b=c$. The product is an $a\times d$ matrix. I always draw this “inner-outer” diagram:

$$[\underbrace{a\times \overbrace{b] \times [c}^{\text{match}} \times d}_{\text{product}}]$$

So say $\boldsymbol{A}\in\Bbb{R}^{r\times c}$, meaning $\boldsymbol{A}$ is an $r\times c$ matrix (with real entries).

Then $\boldsymbol{A}^2$ exists if and only if $r=c$. The resultant is another $r\times c$ matrix, which we know must be square since $r$ must equal $c$. This can again and again be multiplied by an $r × c = r × r = c × c$ matrix.

---

To be more explicit:

> $$\boldsymbol{A}
> = \left[ \begin{matrix}
> A(1,1) & A(1,2) & \cdots & A(1,c) \\[2ex]
> A(2,1) & A(2,2) & \cdots & A(2,c) \\[2ex]
> \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\[2ex]
> A(r,1) & A(r,2) & \cdots & A(r,c) \\[2ex]
> \end{matrix} \right]$$
>
> $$
> \boldsymbol{A}^2
> = 
> \left[ \begin{matrix}
> A(1,1) & A(1,2) & \cdots & A(1,m) \\[2ex]
> A(2,1) & A(2,2) & \cdots & A(2,m) \\[2ex]
> \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\[2ex]
> A(m,1) & A(m,2) & \cdots & A(m,m) \\[2ex]
> \end{matrix} \right]
> \left[ \begin{matrix}
> A(1,1) & A(1,2) & \cdots & A(1,m) \\[2ex]
> A(2,1) & A(2,2) & \cdots & A(2,m) \\[2ex]
> \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\[2ex]
> A(m,1) & A(m,2) & \cdots & A(m,m) \\[2ex]
> \end{matrix} \right]
> =
> \left[ \begin{matrix}
> B(1,1) & B(1,2) & \cdots & B(1,m) \\[2ex]
> B(2,1) & B(2,2) & \cdots & B(2,m) \\[2ex]
> \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\[2ex]
> B(m,1) & B(m,2) & \cdots & B(m,m) \\[2ex]
> \end{matrix} \right]$$
>
> $$\bbox[yellow,5px]{B(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^{m}A(x,k) \, A(k,y)}$$

Comment: If $r \neq c$ then $A^n$ is not valid? Do you know any source for this definition?

Comment: @Mohammad No, it is valid if **and only if** $r=c$. The definition is covered [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixMultiplication.html) and is considered common knowledge among mathematicians. You can arrive at this information yourself simply by [Googling “matrix multiplication”](https://www.google.com/search?q=matrix+multiplication&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us&client=safari).

Comment: This source explains the matrix multiplication. But the question is about raising a matrix to the power of n. It depends on how $A^n$ expands into multiplications. Which again depends on the definition of $A^n$. If it collides with the first approach that I provided, then it will still be valid if $r \neq c$. Now, do you know any source on defining $A^n$?

Comment: @Mohammad In any ring with operations "$+$" and "$\times$" and an element $x$ in the ring and $k$ a natural number (*which is in particular not necessarily a part of the ring*), we shorthand $\underbrace{x+x+x+\dots+x}_{k~\text{times}}$ as $k\cdot x$.  Further we shorthand $\underbrace{x\times x\times x\times \dots\times x}_{k~\text{times}}$ as $x^k$.  Linear algebra borrows the same notation.  It is important to note that the "multiplication" in $k\cdot x$ can be very different than the multiplication $\times$ and is referred to as "scalar multiplication."

Comment: The definition I gave is found in most if not all books on abstract algebra (*with perhaps slight differences, they might choose to notate as $kx$ instead of $k\cdot x$*).  If you insist on a specific citation, consider [this link to wolfram mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixPower.html).

Comment: @Mohammad $$\boldsymbol{A}^2 = \boldsymbol{A}\times\boldsymbol{A}=\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{A}$$ which is what I’ve explained, but in general terms.

Comment: @Mohammad I've updated my answer